# Remove extra line break written with TextStream.WriteLine()

Tags: vba

I have following vba code which write items in the ArrayList to file with TextStream.

```
Sub WriteListAsCSV(list As Object, filePath As String)
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath, True)
    Dim line As Variant
    For Each line In list
        ts.WriteLine (line)
   Next line
   ts.Close
End Sub
```

Problem is I'm getting extra linebreak at the end of the file.

I can do like following but I don't want to check at each loop for that single linebreak.

```
Sub WriteListAsCSV(list As Object, filePath As String)
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Set ts = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath, True)
    Dim line As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To list.Count
        line = list(i)
        ts.Write (line)
        'If not last line
        If Not i = list.Count Then
            'Write blankline
            ts.WriteLine()
        End If
   Next
   ts.Close
End Sub
```

Is there any way to remove one character back like <kbd>Backspace</kbd> button in VBA? Or another neat trick to do this?

Comment: as little simplification:
`For i = 0 To list.Count-1`
`ts.WriteLine (line)`
`Next`
`ts.Write (line)`

Comment: *Why* don't you want to check at each iteration?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I think it will be faster to issue backspace button command (or move the file cursor like in C, Java and remove linebreak character) at the end of loop than to check at each loop if it's the last iteration. I'm new to vba so I'm just out of curiosity :)

Answer (score 3):

### Idea

My idea was to remove the last charaters corresponding to the linebreak, which are `Chr(10)` or `Chr(13)` and sometimes both, using the file length.

### How to do

While I was checking about how to use a function I found this: **[Remove last carriage return file](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/05/20/how-can-i-remove-the-last-carriage-return-linefeed-in-a-text-file.aspx)** which covers exactly my idea ... 
Maybe have a look it's pretty clear.

**EDIT** (cf @ Siddharth Rout comment) 
Modified and commented version of the code (In case of the link dies. I take no credit for this code)

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("path\to\file", 1)     ' -- 1:read

strFile = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

' We check if the two last characters correspond to a linebreak:
If Right(strFile, 2) = vbCrLf Then 
    ' If so, we remove those charaters:
    strFile = Left(strFile, Len(strFile)- 2)
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("path\to\file", 2) ' -- 2:write
    objFile.Write strFile
    objFile.Close
End If
```

I'm not sure it's the more elegant way to do but it seems to be a pretty valid one. Hope this works for you.

Comment: I understand your need of not copying it but it actually makes sense in adding relevant extract from that link here. It would be beneficial for future visitors if the link that you gave died ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Good advice. Don't hesitate to edit/comment if you think this could be improved

Comment: + 1 For your efforts :)

Comment: Thanks! especially since you are the Top VBA contributor ^^